# laravel submitting multiple rows of a form to mysql by creating duplicate rows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

i have this form in larvel that will submit data to mysql database
every time i click `Add More`new row is created using script i want to submit all the rows at ones

```
<form action={{route('invetory.create')}} method="post">
    @csrf
    <div id="service">
        <input type="text" name="item"/>
        <input type="text" name="tax" />
        <input name="price" type="text" />
        <input name="selling_price" type="text" />
        <input name="total_price" type="text" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>   
<a class="btn-floating btn-primary" id="addmore"   onclick="duplicate()">Add More</a>
```

input fields duplicating script

```
<script>
function duplicate() {    
    var original = document.getElementById('service');
    var rows = original.parentNode.rows;
    var i = rows.length - 1;
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplic" + (i); // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, rows[i]);
}</script>
```

invetory.create route in web.php

```
`Route::post('/inventory', 'App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController@create')->name('invetory.create');`
```

funtion in  InventoryController.php

```
public function create(Request $REQUEST){
    Inventory::Create($REQUEST->all());
    return redirect()->action([InventoryController::class, 'index']);
}
```

Comment: Clicking the `Add More` link just creates a new section in the form, it does not submit the form to the server

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes but  how can  create a submit button that will submit all the input filds at ones?  also   lets consider `<input name="price" type="text" />`  when i click add more the same input field will be duplicated so the  input name will be same wont that create a problem when i submit

Comment: Suggest you use `name="price[]"` or maybe also use your counter for `name="price"+i` The  `name="price[]"` option would fit better with your clone

Comment: can u add a answer so i can try it

Comment: You can try it from the comment, saves me having to write the code for you

Comment: i am getting folowing errorIlluminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\Users\vivek\laravelprocject\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 1010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247839/discussion-between-menu-cd-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, what I get from your question is that you want to insert multiple data in single query.

You have to give field name using array other wise it is difficult to differentiate multiple data using same key name. Array will differentiate your data using index value with same name.

Here is a simple example what you want to implement. According to this you can create your own format. Here I used table structure, if you want you can use div structure.

**In Blade file:-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container"> 
   
    <form action="{{route('invetory.create')}}" method="POST">
   
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">  
            <tr>
                <th>item</th>
                <th>tax</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>selling_price</th>
                <th>total_price</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td><input type="text" name="invetory[0][item]"  class="form-control" /></td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="invetory[0][tax]"  class="form-control" /></td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="invetory[0][price]"  class="form-control" /></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="invetory[0][selling_price]"  class="form-control" /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="invetory[0][total_price]"  class="form-control" /></td>

            </tr>  
        </table> 
       <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    var i = 0;
       
    $("#add").click(function(){
   
        ++i;
   
        $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="invetory['+i+'][item]"  class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="invetory['+i+'][tax]"  class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="invetory['+i+'][price]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="invetory['+i+'][selling_price]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="invetory['+i+'][total_price]" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
    });
   
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });  
   
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

And in **controller** you have to do like this

```
public function create(Request $request){
    foreach ($request->invetory as $key => $value) {
        Inventory::create($value);
    }
    return redirect()->action([InventoryController::class, 'index']);
}
```

Comment: aswome thats how answer must be

Answer (score -1):

You may use

```
public function create(Request $REQUEST){
Inventory::firstOrCreate($REQUEST->all());
return redirect()->action([InventoryController::class, 'index']);
```

}

You may also check [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#belongs-to-many-first-or-new)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).